# Clean declaring and using variables in Android

Tags: android, performance, variables

Every once in a while, entering in a new Activity requires updating values in let's say several `TextView`s. So let's say I got n `String`s to write in n `TextView`s of the starting Activity.

Which one is the best approach to guarantee good performance and providing "clean code"?

**Variant 1** (The way I actually apply):
I declare a single `TextView` variable "tempText" as global variable and assign the TextView to update to this variable (alternatively in a extra method).
Alternatively, a) is doing the whole procedere in the `onCreate()`, while b) is handle everything in a method called e.g. `updateTextViews()`

```
(...)

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView tempText;

    public onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        (...)

        tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
        tempText.setText(string_1);

        tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_2);
        tempText.setText(string_2);

        (...)

        tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_n);
        tempText.setText(string_n);
    }
}
```

**Variant 2** :
I declare a single `TextView` variable "tempText" as variable in the `onCreate()` or the respective method and assign the TextView to update to this variable.
The rest is in analogy to Variant 1.

```
(...)

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    public onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        (...)

        private TextView tempText;

        tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
        tempText.setText(string_1);

        tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_2);
        tempText.setText(string_2);

        (...)

        tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_n);
        tempText.setText(string_n);
    }
}
```

**Variant 3:**
I declare a global `TextView` variable for every `TextView` to update. This, as far as I know, needs more space in the RAM, but I don't know about the impact to velocity. Also here, are there differences between handling it in the `onCreate()` (a)) or in a seperate method (b))?

```
(...)

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView tempText_1;
    private TextView tempText_2;
    (...)
    private TextView tempText_n;

    public onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        (...)

        tempText_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
        tempText_1.setText(string_1);

        tempText_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_2);
        tempText_2.setText(string_2);

        (...)

        tempText_n = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_n);
        tempText_n.setText(string_n);
    }
}
```

**Variant 4:**
I declare a `TextView` variable for every `TextView` to update in the `onCreate()` or the respective method which handles this. The rest is in analogy to Variant 3?

```
(...)

public class MyActivity extends Activity{


    public onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        (...)

        private TextView tempText_1;
        private TextView tempText_2;
        (...)
        private TextView tempText_n;

        tempText_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
        tempText_1.setText(string_1);

        tempText_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_2);
        tempText_2.setText(string_2);

        (...)

        tempText_n = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_n);
        tempText_n.setText(string_n);
    }
}
```

Which one is the "best" method? Variants 1 and 2 provide reserving only one memory address in the RAM and use this, while according to Robert C. Martins "Clean Code" the variables are really ambiguous. Option 3 and 4 would be the exact opposite. But for the rest I'm not very conscious of other effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I use a Variant 3 if I need to access the TextViews again elsewhere in Activity (i.e. in onResume, which is where I usually put my static UI updates). If the setText is a one-shot thing, I do something like --

```
((TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv_1 ) ).setText( string_1 );
((TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv_2 ) ).setText( string_2 );
```

If there's any doubt that the view might not be there (i.e. when you're modifying layouts during dev), I'd use a wrapper such as --

```
private void safeSetText( int id, String caption ) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( id );
    if( tv != null )
        tv.setText( caption );
    else
        Log.d( "..... " );
}
```

And then in onCreate:
    safeSetText( R.id.tv_1, string_1 );
    safeSetText( R.id.tv_2, string_2 );

Comment: what is better way to declaring those stuff, like in onCreate or onResume, how to increase performance  on application.

Comment: @HiteshDhamshaniya, I don't think this will have a noticeable performance impact, but placing this in `onCreate()` will make it run only once, while the `onResume()` might be invoked multiple times. These objects are merely references, so they occupy eight bytes each. Again, a handful of references to widgets are negligible in the context of a application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the value through out the this activity, declare it as a member variable in the class as you normally do. There is nothing like you declare inside OnCreate, it is still a member variable. It is as good as declaring in the class body, it will improve the readability.

Also if you are declaring a member variable anywhere, it is going to occupy the same amount of ram. There is nothing you gain/loose there.

If you are sure that a variable is going to be used only locally, declare it locally, it will be allocated in stack instead of heap, and it will vanish as soon as you exit the block.

There is no such android optimized way of declaring variables as such. You can follow normal Object oriented/Java way of doing things.